# How can I set the position variable only in it's parent rather than on every inherited class?

Tags: c#

I currently have 4 classes that inherits Buildable class. For each derived class, I have to set it's position every time I inherits the buildable class. Is there any way to make this more cleaner? I think showing the code will make it more easier to understand.

```
public class BuildableData
{
    public Vector3 position;
}

public class StockpileData : BuildableData
{
    public int woodCount = 0;

    public static StockpileData Create(Stockpile stockpile)
    {
        return new StockpileData
        {
            position = stockpile.transform.position,
            woodCount = stockpile.WoodCount
        };
    }
}

public class HouseData : BuildableData
{
    public static HouseData Create(House house)
    {
        return new HouseData
        {
            position = house.transform.position, // I'm talking about this one? I have to set it everytime I inherit BuildableData
        };
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make it automatically set by just passing the object to the constructor or maybe using reflection?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoMapper is the right library here to solve the mentioned problem as it helps to map one object's properties to another object's properties. Below code snippet will help to configure the same in your project.

```
using AutoMapper;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
            {
                mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
            });

            var mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();

            var house = new House();
            var houseData = mapper.Map<HouseData>(house);

            var stockpile = new Stockpile();
            var stockpileData = mapper.Map<StockpileData>(stockpile);
        }
    }

    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<House, HouseData>()
                .ForMember(destination => destination.Position,
                           source => source.MapFrom(m => m.transform.Position));

            CreateMap<Stockpile, StockpileData>()
                .ForMember(destination => destination.Position,
                           source => source.MapFrom(m => m.transform.Position));
        }
    }
}
```